# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'bool'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to calculate some records in Python but I got the error message above.

```
for i in (0, ConsCount):
    if ConsCount > 0:
        for x in range(0, ConsCount):
            ConsBlendTable = df [(df.CONS_BATCH == ConsTable['Batch'].iloc[i])]
            ConsBlendCount = len(ConsBlendTable.index)
            
            for p in (0, ConsBlendCount):
                if ConsBlendCount > 0:
                    Cons_Qty= ConsTable['Qty'].iloc[i]
                    Cons_Exit = False
                    PartCons_Qty = 0
                    TPartCons_Qty=0
                    ConsPosting=False
                    for j in range(0,ConsBlendCount):
                        DeclDate= ConsBlendTable['DeclarationDate'].iloc[p]
                        if DeclDate <= ((ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]) and (ConsBlendTable['FirstDate'].iloc[p]<=ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p])):
                            Sendung_Content >= ConsBlendTable['Remain_Bestand'][p] + (Cons_Qty + TPartCons_Qty)
                            if Sendung_Content >= 0:
                                Cons_Exit =True
                                PartCons_Qty = Cons_Qty - TPartCons_Qty
                                TCons_Qty = ConsBlendTable['AC_DispoBest'][p] - Sendung_Content
```

And I got the error message at this line:

```
 if DeclDate <= ((ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]) and (ConsBlendTable['FirstDate'].iloc[p]<=ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p])):
```

**TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'bool'**

The values are date in the original df but as I used the iloc it converted into Timestamp.

Comment: you are comparing a Timestamp (DeclDate) with a bool, because the right side is a boolean expression.
What do you expect to get from the right side?

Maybe you need to move the parenthesis first compare `(DeclDate <= (ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]) )` and then you have the remaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have added the brackets incorrectly:

With your current code:

```
if DeclDate <= ((ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]) and (ConsBlendTable['FirstDate'].iloc[p]<=ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]))
```

`((ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]) and (ConsBlendTable['FirstDate'].iloc[p]<=ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]))`
evaluates to a boolean and thus you are getting the error.

Try changing the above line to:

```
if DeclDate <= (ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p]) and (ConsBlendTable['FirstDate'].iloc[p]<=ConsTable['PstgDate'].iloc[p])
```